# Walk-through into make (menu)config's options

Tags: kernel, make

I need to customize the kernel a lot for a custom system. Most of my changes concern the kernel's memory usage (something like an embedded kernel).

There are a lot of things enabled by default in the source, and I will not use them all, or will use as a module only.

I know the functionality of many options, yet some options are too advanced for me.

I've already searched Google for the options that I'm confused with but, I couldn't find anything useful regarding them.

I'd like to know if there's any walk-through/reference when it comes to the kernel's menuconfig options.

Comment: There are no walkthroughs on Kernel Building persay, allthough there are some on the menuconfig interface.  Tuning a kernel, comes with innate knowledge of the components of your system, embedded or otherwise, and a few commands like `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `lspci`, along with `lsusb` and your motherboard instruction booklet.

Answer (score 1):

you can start by reading [the walktrougth of gentoo linux about configuring the kernel](https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=7), there are some usefull tips on how to start. from there you will have to google all your hardware chipsets (some of them you can find using `lspci` and `lsusb` and use `cat /proc/cpuinfo` for more information about your cpu.

Read the descriptions of the kernel-modules carefully, they tell you if it is safe to enable/disable it or how to find if you need them using the technical info of your hardware and your best friend, google.

Good luck with it.